# Why does in ASP.net Core MVC causes Javascript Error when I pass the string on my model?

Tags: javascript, regex, asp.net-mvc

I'm using ASP.net Core MVC and I'm trying to pass a RegexValidation from a Model as below:

**Default.cshtml:**

```
@model MyClass.MyModel
<script>
    $().ready(function() {
        jQuery.validator.addMethod("regex",
            function(value, element) {
                var rgx = RegExp(/@(Html.Raw(Model.ValidationRegex))/); //<-- This creates the error
                return rgx.test(value);
            },
            "some message");
    });
</script>
```

But I get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'return'` Javascript Error.

But if I write static as below, no problem occurs:

```
@model MyClass.MyModel
    <script>
        $().ready(function() {
            jQuery.validator.addMethod("regex",
                function(value, element) {
                    var rgx = RegExp(/^(?:http(s)?:\/\/)?[\w.-]+(?:\.[\w\.-]+)+[\w\-\._~:/?#[\]@!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=.]+$/); //<-- No problem
                    return rgx.test(value);
                },
                "some message");
        });
    </script>
```

What I don't understand is the outputs in the `Browser Source` are **exactly** the same! And this is how it appears in **BOTH** cases.

[image]

Why does my first approach create that JavaScript error?

Comment: You should not use a regex literal inside a RegExp constructor. Use `var rgx = RegExp(@(Html.Raw(Model.ValidationRegex)));`

Comment: You are right! There was a reason why I used literal inside which I'll post as an answer and explain. Thank you again!